# Correct way for creating apparmor hats in separate file

Tags: php, php-fpm, apparmor

I'm trying to re-enforce the security of my LAMP config

In my configuration, each website consists in :

- One Unix account
- One MySQL database accessible only from one MySQL account
- One VirtualHost defined in a separate file
- One php-fpm pool defined in a separate file

Now I'm trying to re-enforce the security by using apparmor.

I'm starting with profile for php-fpm.

My idea is to have a general php-fpm config and a specific config for each php-fpm pool.

As far as I have understand, the general config is a *profile* and the specific config should be defined as a a *hat*.

I would like to have this specific *hat* config defined in a separate file.

In *complain mode* everything seems to works (at least I have nothing when I use the command *aa-logprof*)

This is how I've made it

Let's consider a site https://www.test.com having a Linux user "test" and a php-fpm pool "test.conf"

1° In the php-fpm pool **/etc/php/8.1/fpm/pool.d/test.conf** I've added this to define a hat named test

```
apparmor_hat = test
```

2° I have defined my global rules into **/etc/apparmor.d/php-fpm**. This is the config I've made to enable the hats in separate file

```
include if exists <php-fpm.d>
...
signal send peer=php-fpm//*,
signal send set=quit peer=php-fpm//**,
signal send set=kill peer=php-fpm//**,
signal send set=term peer=php-fpm//**,
...
change_profile -> php-fpm//**,
```

3° My test *hat* has been defined into **/etc/apparmor.d/php-fpm.d/test** like this

```
   ^test flags=(complain,attach_disconnected) {
    /var/run/php/php-fpm-test.sock rwlk,
    /var/log/php-fpm/test.access.log rw,
    ...
    deny /var/www/** r,
    owner /home/test/www/** rw,
  }
```

When I try to pass to *enforce mode*, it seems the rules I've defined in the main apparmor *profile* /etc/apparmor.d/php-fpm are NOT taken into account by my *hat*

This is my first apparmor profile and I've made this like I have understand.

I don't know what I've missed. Did I miss a best practice ?

**EDIT**

I've discovered I can put the main profile in *enforce mode*.

The problem I'm experiencing is only when I put a hat in *enforce mode* and when I try to restart the php service

In this case, I see the following error message

```
php8.1-fpm.service: Failed to kill control group /system.slice/php8.1-fpm.service, ignoring: Permission denied
```